# How to Close keycloak webview after keycloak.logout() in react native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, authentication, keycloak

I am integrating keycloak auth in react native app. After keycloak.logout() it redirect me to login page again but I want to close that window. How can I do that?

Added keycloak.logout({redirectUri:"example://homepage"}) not working